# UnreachableBrowserException in Selenium webdriver scripts

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:09:54'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_29'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

This is the error message which gets displayed when I am trying to run my scripts?
Scenario :My one java file has login function and second has creation of a new Account after login
Kindly advise.

Login.java:

```
public class LoginPage 
{ 

    public static WebDriver driver;  

    public static final LoginPage login = new LoginPage(new FirefoxDriver()); 

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) 
    {    
        LoginPage.driver = driver;  
    } 

    public static void loginAs(String username, String password) 
    {  
        DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

        ieCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true); 

        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(); 

        proxy.setProxyAutoconfigUrl("http://www.config.barclays.co.uk:9000/");

        driver.close();

        ieCapabilities. setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy); 

        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ieCapabilities);

        driver.get("https://login.salesforce.com"); 

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //Login to Salesforce Application
        try
        {
            driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(username);

            driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(password);   

            driver.findElement(By.id("Login")).click();

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(75, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }
        catch(Exception e1)
        {

            System.out.println(e1 +"Your login attempt has failed. The username or password may be incorrect, or your location or login time may be restricted. Please contact the administrator at your company for help.");
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        login.loginAs("me@example.com", "Pa$$word"); 
    }
}
```

Second File where I am trying to click on Opportunity tab of my Sales force application :
CreatOpportunity.java these lines are under my main argument

```
LoginPage.login.loginAs("username", "password");

LoginPage.login.driver.findElement(By.id("Opportunity_Tab")).click();
```

Running my second file allows me to launch my application but does not detect the click on the Opprtunity tab and throws me the error mentioned above

Comment: Only for this script you are getting this error or for any script? If for every script try to restart all your browser instances

Comment: I am facing this error message for all:Foreg: LoginPage.login.loginAs("user Name", "Password"); LoginPage.driver.findElement(By.id("Opportunity_Tab")).click();   Then I am getting the same error, here loginPage helps me in logging in to the application and second line is navigating to a Opportunity section of the application. Kindly advise

Comment: Could you please paste your code

Comment: Vikram I have added my exact code. Kindly advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just give a try with by putting below line after login.

```
driver.switchTo.defaultContent();
```

try with below code.

```
public class LoginPage {
    public static WebDriver driver;  

    public LoginPage() 
    {    
         DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
         ieCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true); 
         Proxy proxy = new Proxy(); 
         proxy.setProxyAutoconfigUrl("http://www.config.barclays.co.uk:9000/");
         ieCapabilities. setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy); 
         LoginPage.driver = new FirefoxDriver(ieCapabilities); 
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } 

    public static void loginAs(String username, String password) {  



        driver.get("https://login.salesforce.com"); 
        //Login to Salesforce Application
        try
            { 
            driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(username);
            driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(password);   
            driver.findElement(By.id("Login")).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(75, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        catch(Exception e1) {

            System.out.println(e1 +"Your login attempt has failed. The username or password may be incorrect, or your location or login time may be restricted. Please contact the administrator at your company for help.");
        }
}

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LoginPage login = new LoginPage(); 
        login.loginAs("me@example.com", "Pa$$word"); 
        FileTwo.clickOpportunity(driver);
    }

}
```

FileTwo

```
public class FileTwo
{
 public static void clickOpportunity(WebDriver driver)
 throws Exception
 {
      driver.findElement(By.id("Opportunity_Tab")).click();
 }
}
```

Comment: HI Santosh, I am able to click the Opportunity tab using the scripts in my single java file. What I am trying to do here from reusablity point of view is CreateLogin(which is one fil) and then next function/file is clicking on Opportunity tab. So when I am trying to call the login () in another java file. I am getting the above error message... Kindly advise

Answer (score 0):

Selenium throws this error if you call quit() method & try to launch browser again. Workaround is use close() method instead of quit()